# How to put JLabel behind JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jtextarea

I have a `JFrame`, `JLabel` and `JTextArea`. How put layered `JLabel` and `JTexrArea` such that `JTextArea` is just above `Jlabel` (like layered) in the `JFrame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) has ordering for Layers